# How to Represent a 2D Orthogonal Grid (Python)

Tags: python, grid

Basically I have a set of "rooms" (custom class). All the rooms are connected and each room is defined in relation to one or more other rooms. I'm looking for some system to organize these rooms in a 2D grid and designate an arbitrary room as the origin.

```
class room(exits={}) :
    #Other code in here, not relevant
    exits = {}


room_list = {}

room_list['room_1'] = room(exits={'north':'room_2'})
room_list['room_2'] = room(exits={'south':'room_1','west':'room_3'})
room_list['room_3'] = room(exits={'east':'room_2'})
```

So I would like some way to represent these rooms in a grid, other than just room-to-room linking.

Comment: Care to show some code and problem encountered? Also your question not very easy to comprehend.

Comment: I think the end of your question got cut off.

Comment: OK, sorry about that, I added some code and cleared up the cut off line.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is not very clear, it appears that you need something like GraphViz [1]. It is basically a program to automate the layout of block diagrams, which is completely isomorphic to your problem. There is a Python interface, PyGraphViz [2],that may be useful for you.

If you want to generate your own layout engine (comparable to GraphViz), make sure you check out the multidimensional scaling algorithm [3] that is used by the neato component of the GraphViz program.

[1]http://www.graphviz.org/

[2]http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/

[3]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling

I may give some more targeted help if you provide more details about the problem. An example figure (sketch) of what you want to obtain would be good.